# Strip all lines from a file that match a pattern, except the first occurrence

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a directory of .txt files that look like this:

```
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:30
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:30
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]02:00:00
```

I'd like to remove all occurrences of `[LINETYPE]S` except the first, which happens to always be 00:00:00 and on the first line, and then re-save the file to a new location.

That is, `[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]00:00:00` must always be present, but the other lines that start with `[LINETYPE]S` need to be removed.

This is what I came up with, which works except it removes all `[LINETYPE]S` lines, including the first. I can't seem to figure out how to do that part after Googling for a while, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help!

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Samples" -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch "\[LINETYPE\]S"
    } | Set-Content ('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Samples\Final\' + $_.BaseName + '.txt')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Samples" -Filter *.txt |
Foreach-Object {
  $count = 0
  Get-Content $_.FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '\[LINETYPE\]S' -or $count++ -eq 0 } |
      Set-Content ('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Samples\Final\' + $_.BaseName + '.txt')
}
```

The script block passed to `Where-Object` runs in the same scope as the caller, so variable `$count` can be directly updated.

The 1st line that *does* contain `[LINETYPE]S` *is* included, because `$count` is 0 at that point, *after* which `$count` is incremented (`$count++`); subsequent `[LINETYPE]S` are *not* included, because `$count` is then already greater than `0`.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for pointing out the typo - fixed (no parens needed in this case).

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't figure out how to do this via a pipeline [*blush*], so i went with a `foreach` loop and a compound test.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:30
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:30
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]02:00:00
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$KeepFirst = '[LINETYPE]S'

$FoundFirst = $False
$FilteredList = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    if ($IS_Item.StartsWith($KeepFirst))
        {
        if (-not $FoundFirst)
            {
            $IS_Item
            $FoundFirst = $True
            }
        }
        else
        {
        $IS_Item
        }
    }

$FilteredList
```

output ...

```
[LINETYPE]S[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]00:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]00:59:30
[LINETYPE]P[STARTTIME]01:00:00
[LINETYPE]B[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:00
[LINETYPE]C[STARTTIME]01:59:30
```

at that point, you can send the new collection out to a file. [*grin*]